# Generate SQL Statements for database test

Tags: sql, testing, code-generation, code-coverage

I want to do coverage testing for a custom database, checking whether the database provides the correct answer to several sql queries.
Therefor I need lots of sql queries to cover most of the possible sql syntax.
A database structure and a sql grammar is already given.

Is there a tool that can generate sql statements from a existing schema and grammar.

Note: I want to test the database, not the data! The data is assumed to be correct. The generated statements will be executed on my database and on another one, which should deliver the correct answer to a query. Afterward I will compare both answers to check whether my database processes sql correctly.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to test here?  Your question implies that you are testing syntax; syntax of the queries or the DDL that created the schema?  Or do you need to test the data *(which seems more likely)*?  If it's the data, any referential integrity in the schema *(foreign keys, unique indexes, etc)* will already be enforced.  So that leaves testing that your data covers certain corner cases?  But a schema won't help you there *(in terms of defining what SQL tests to generate)*.  You're going to need to be *a lot* more specific in your question for us to be able to help you.

Comment: *(Perhaps giving examples of what you would generate by hand, but want a tool to generate for you.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give Random Query Generator a try, some Database-Developer Teams use it for same reasons.

Code:
https://launchpad.net/randgen

Documentation:
https://github.com/RQG/RQG-Documentation/wiki/Category%3ARandomQueryGenerator

As I can see, you may only need some parts of the tool itself (depends on if you use a MySQL-DB/JDB or not). Especially for MySQL there is a fully automated process described on how to test the queries against an already running server.

I hope this is what you need.